# Android: I need to make application that allows drawing small-sized images on canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I need to create app where I can use images as colors in Paint program in windows, so when I select image it will be copied and when I tap somewhere on canvas it will paste that image there, and so on till I hit save button. The save button should save bitmap as image (idk maybe jpeg format?) and show it in main activity which has grid view and looks like little gallery with painted pictures.

Since I'm learning Android/Java like a month, and its hard for me cause I'm new at programming, I'm not asking for code, just please read this and if you understand what I need, please tell me which topics of Android I should read for making such app

p.s. Thanks and sorry for bad grammar

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about possible operations with `Canvas`. [This is](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/introduction-to-2d-drawing-in-android.html) the good article.

You can read a small article about inage editor creation in [this blog](http://suhebqureshi.blogspot.ru/2013/05/creating-simple-image-editor-in.html).

Comment: thank you :) I'll read about operations 
p.s. links are broken

Comment: Oops, I've fixed the links